# How Can I Perform a Perspective Transform Using a Homography Matrix (3x3) in JavaCV?

Tags: opencv, perspective, javacv, homography, warp

I have been trying for some time now to take an image of a pool table from an arbitrary angle, locate four coordinate pairs (x,y) of the corners, and rotate/warp the image such that the resulting image contains only the table from a bird's eye view. I am using JavaCV to accomplish this task. So far, I have written code which successfully calculates the four corners of the table as shown below (I have coded red cvCircles of radius 25 on the four corners).

[image]

After finding my four corners:
Corner 1 (Bottom Right)
X: 3234 Y: 1858
Corner 2 (Bottom Left)
X: 0 Y: 1801
Corner 3 (Top Right)
X: 2722 Y: 1069
Corner 4 (Top Left)
X: 523 Y: 1030

### I attempted to use cvFindHomography and then cvWarpPerspectve to accomplish this. My code can be found below:

```
// Initialize Table Corners as Image Coordinates
    float[] aImg = {
        corners.get(0).x(), corners.get(0).y(), // BR X: 3234 Y: 1858
        corners.get(1).x(), corners.get(1).y(), // BL X: 0    Y: 1801
        corners.get(2).x(), corners.get(2).y(), // TR X: 2722 Y: 1069
        corners.get(3).x(), corners.get(3).y()  // TL X: 523  Y: 1030
    };

// Initialize World Coordinates (Are these even correct? How do I determine these?)
    float[] aWorld = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f,1.0f
    };

// Create 3x3 Homography Matrix
    CvMat homography = cvCreateMat(3, 3, opencv_core.CV_32FC1);
    opencv_imgproc.cvGetPerspectiveTransform(aImg, aWorld, homography);
    System.out.println(homography.toString());

// Create imgWarped and Warp Perspective
    IplImage imgWarped = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
    opencv_imgproc.cvWarpPerspective(img, imgWarped, homography, opencv_imgproc.CV_INTER_LINEAR, CvScalar.ZERO);

// Create Canvas and Display Image
    CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Warped Image");
    canvas.showImage(imgWarped);
    canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

The 3x3 Homography Matrix I'm obtaining is:
[ 0.0011688289, 7.928632E-4, -1.4279466
  -8.698455E-5, 0.0049045905, -5.006235
  -2.8205379E-5, 0.0015696458, 1.0 ]

### **Unfortunately, the result is a purely black image containing *nothing*. Am I approaching this incorrectly? Any advice, code, pseudocode, etc. would be GREATLY APPRECIATED!

### Thank you so much for reading.**

Comment: Have you tried using the 4 original corners of your `img` as coordinates for `aWorld`?

Comment: Yeah but unfortunately this did not work. However, I did find a solution. By altering aWorld parameters 1.0f to the img.width()/img.height() values I was able to successfully warp the perspective. Thank you for your help Sam! And also for developing JavaCV :)